# Vue.js access parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got a child-component that has this method:

```
getSubscriptions () {
    MessageService.subscriptions()
            this.$parent.loading = true;
            .then((data) => {
                if (data.data.subscriptions == null) {
                    this.noSubscriptions = true;
                } else {
                    this.subscriptions = data.data.subscriptions;
                }

                this.$parent.loading = false;
            }).bind(this);
}
```

So I want to show a load circle in my parent component I access it like this:

```
this.$parent.loading
```

(My parent component has a data attribute called `loading`)

But when I try to compile that with gulp ^ I receive:

```
[14:52:56] Starting 'browserify'...
  46 |                             }
  47 | 
> 48 | t                           this.$parent.loading = false;
     |                             ^
  49 |                         }).bind(this);
  50 |             },
  51 | 
{ SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token (48:28)
  46 |                             }
  47 | 
> 48 | t                           this.$parent.loading = false;
     |                             ^
  49 |                         }).bind(this);
  50 |             },
```

What could be wrong here?

(I'm using `Vue.js 1.0`)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're putting a new statement in the middle of a promise setup.  You need to rearrange the code:

```
this.$parent.loading = true;
MessageService.subscriptions()
        .then((data) => {
```

However, I wouldn't directly access the parent like this.  It creates a tight coupling between parent and child -- this component will only work if the parent exposes a `loading` flag.

Instead, look into [custom events](http://v1.vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Parent-Child-Communication).